# Como validar um script no PEP8?

Tags: python, validação, pep8

Notei algumas perguntas que perguntavam sobre o PEP8, algo como *"desta maneira esta correto?"*, exemplo recente:

- [Problemas com as regras de indentação PEP8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/259913/3635)

Então me surgiu a duvida, será que existe algum meio de saber se o código esta adequado e qual linha talvez não esteja nos conformes?

Pode ser online ou uma biblioteca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe o https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle, para instalar via `pip` use o seguinte comando:

```
pip install pycodestyle
```

Exemplo de uso em um arquivo com "problemas":

```
pycodestyle --first script_com_problemas.py
```

A saída será algo como:

> script_com_problemas.py:69:11: E401 multiple imports on one line
>
> script_com_problemas.py:77:1: E302 expected 2 blank lines, found 1
>
> script_com_problemas.py:88:5: E301 expected 1 blank line, found 0
>
> script_com_problemas.py:222:34: W602 deprecated form of raising exception
>
> script_com_problemas.py:347:31: E211 whitespace before '('
>
> script_com_problemas.py:357:17: E201 whitespace after '{'
>
> script_com_problemas.py:472:29: E221 multiple spaces before operator
>
> script_com_problemas.py:544:21: W601 .has_key() is deprecated, use 'in'

---

Se precisar atualizar o pacote `pycodestyle` execute:

```
pip install --upgrade pycodestyle
```

Se desejar desinstalar execute:

```
pip uninstall pycodestyle
```

> **Nota:** o pacote `pep8` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8) na verdade é o mesmo que o `pycodestyle`, mas foi renomeado, não instale o pacote `pepe8`, irá emitir uma mensagem avisando para remover e instalar o `pycodestyle`

---

### Alternativa:

#### PyLint

- Site: https://www.pylint.org

Para instalar execute:

```
pip install pylint
```

Para checar o seu script:

```
pylint script_com_problemas.py
```

---

### Validando o PEP8 online

Acaso esteja em uma máquina que lhe impossibilita de instalar algo é possível usar o seguinte serviço online para validar o seu script:

- http://pep8online.com

> Se encontrar mais serviços assim irei adicionar posteriormente

Comment: Você conseguiu validar o código da [pergunta citada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/259913/problemas-com-as-regras-de-indenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-pep8) com esse script [pep8.py]? Eu não consegui :(

Comment: @vnbrs testei agora, ambos validaram, pode ser algum bug, vou testar as ferramentas instaladas, no entanto não domino o PEP8, talvez exista a *remota* possibilidade de ambos serem validos. Não que eu esteja discordando da sua resposta.

Comment: @vnbrs estranhamente quando usado dentro de `[...]` a validação é ignorada, segue: https://gist.github.com/brcontainer/b549a7e6149cb913bf6d3db9b7362fa4